# compile error while upgrading to 3.0 version

Tags: android, build.gradle, updates, android-studio-3.0

I want to run my old project in android 3.0 version. But it is showing the runtime error please anyone helps me to resolve my issue.

My project contains submodules.

I am using apt also if I change `compile` into `implementation` in the `gradle` it is showing the `apt error`. What I do. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

here is the error.

```
 Error:Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :library:
  - debugApiElements
   - debugRuntimeElements
  - releaseApiElements
  - releaseRuntimeElements
All of them match the consumer attributes:
   - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
    - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
    - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
    - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
    - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
 - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
    - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
  - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
  - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
  - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
  - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
  - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
  - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
  - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
   - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
  - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
  - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
  - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
```

Here is my Main Gradle:

```
      buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'


}
 }

 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
    }
    google()
}


ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.1"

    minSdkVersion = 14
    targetSdkVersion = 23

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

    lintAbortOnError = false

    // QuickBlox SDK version
    qbSdkVersion = '3.1.0'

    versionName = "3.0"

    testRunnerVersion = "0.4.1"


    // Dependency versions
    playServicesVersion = '9.8.0'
    supportV4Version = '23.1.1'
    appcompatV7Version = '23.1.1'
    recyclerviewV7Version = '23.2.1'
    supportAnnotationsVersion = '23.1.1'
    designVersion = '23.1.1'

    uilVersion = '1.9.0'
    glideVersion = '3.6.1'
    pullToRefreshVersion = '3.2.3'
    stickyListHeaders = '2.7.0'
    robotoTextViewVersion = '2.4.3'
    stickersVersion = '0.7.3'
    crashlyticsVersion = '2.2.2'
}


 }
```

Here is my app Gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
configurations{
    all*.exclude module: 'servlet-api'
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    }
}
configurations {
    // Initializes placeholder configurations that the Android plugin can use when targeting
    // the corresponding variant of the app.
    demoDebugCompile {}
    fullReleaseCompile {}

}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':library')
compile project(':simpl3r')

compile project(':androidHorizontalListView')


compile  'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile  files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
compile  files('libs/bugsense-3.6.jar')
compile  files('libs/espresso-1.1-bundled.jar')
compile  files('libs/sample-2.4.1.jar')
compile  files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile  files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile  files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
compile  files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2-SNAPSHOT-with-sources.jar')
compile  files('libs/volley.jar')
compile  files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile  files('libs/gcm.jar')

compile  files('libs/mint-5.2.1.jar')
compile project(':swipelibrary')


compile  files('libs/glide-3.7.0.jar')
compile  files('libs/glide-3.7.0-javadoc.jar')
compile  'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
compile  'org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.7'
compile  'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher:1.2'
compile  'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile  'com.thefinestartist:utils:0.9.1'
apt  'com.thefinestartist:compilers:0.9.1'
compile  'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
compile  'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12'
compile  'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'
compile  'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

//implemented retrofit.
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile  'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

compile  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'
compile  'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'

compile  'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile  'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.3.1'
compile project(':sample-chat')
compile project(':sample-pushnotifications')


compile  'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.1.0'
compile  "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0"

compile project(':sample-core')


}

ext {
compileSdkVersion = 26
buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

minSdkVersion = 14
targetSdkVersion = 23

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

lintAbortOnError = false

// QuickBlox SDK version
qbSdkVersion = '3.1.0'

versionName = "3.0"

testRunnerVersion = "0.4.1"


// Dependency versions
playServicesVersion = '9.8.0'
supportV4Version = '23.1.1'
appcompatV7Version = '23.1.1'
recyclerviewV7Version = '23.2.1'
supportAnnotationsVersion = '23.1.1'
designVersion = '23.1.1'

uilVersion = '1.9.0'
glideVersion = '3.6.1'
pullToRefreshVersion = '3.2.3'
stickyListHeaders = '2.7.0'
robotoTextViewVersion = '2.4.3'
stickersVersion = '0.7.3'
crashlyticsVersion = '2.2.2'
}
```

Please help me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
compile project(':library')
compile project(':simpl3r')
```

To

```
compile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'default')
compile project(path: ':simpl3r', configuration: 'default')
```

Update1

```
implementation project(path: ':library')
implementation project(path: ':simpl3r')
.
. 
.
```

Comment: If i change that line iam getting another error related to apt

Comment: try this implementation project(':library')

Comment: if i change like that iam getting this error................Unable to resolve dependency for ':sample@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform file 'sample-chat-release.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform ExtractAarTransform

Comment: remove configuration: default and try, check updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161082/discussion-between-lassie-and-minnukaanae).

Answer (score 0):

Change this . Hope this  Help.

```
 compile project(':library')
 compile project(':simpl3r')
 compile project(':androidHorizontalListView')
 compile project(':swipelibrary')
 compile project(':sample-chat')
 compile project(':sample-pushnotifications')
```

to

```
 implementation project(':library')
 implementation project(':simpl3r')
 implementation project(':androidHorizontalListView')
 implementation project(':swipelibrary')
 implementation project(':sample-chat')
 implementation project(':sample-pushnotifications')
```

**UPDATE:** 
You can remove the line :

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

Your app level `Gradle` dependencies should include

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Comment: If i change like that iam getting this error...............Unable to resolve dependency for ':tweak2@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :sample-pushnotifications.

Comment: ha  i changed like that . iam getting another error .........Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin. Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.

Comment: after remove the apt .Iam getting this error...........
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: try to change this line `apt  'com.thefinestartist:compilers:0.9.1'` to `annotationProcessor 'com.thefinestartist:compilers:0.9.1'` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161096/discussion-between-dharmishtha-and-lassie).

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues here:

1. using different versions of android support libs (example: your recyclerview is `23.0.+` but support design is `23.4.0` etc.)
2. declaring an ext with your lib versions, but actually never using them anywhere?
3. same ext declared in app gradle and projects gradle? (and not using them in both?)
4. compileSdkVersion 26 doesn't match version of support lib (you use various 23 version of it)
5. Using very old versions like for example google play services 9.8.0 etc.
6. still using deprecated `compile` instead of `implementation`

The list is probably not complete, but I hope that helps to get you started organising your gradle files